# SPFX Field Extension

Tags: spfx, 2019

Can I have multiple Field extension in the same project? I tried to define multiple fields in the same project but for some reason it takes only the first one defined.
I tried also packaging both fields but this doesn't work either. The behavior of the fields are not reflected.

Comment: I have experienced this too.  I seem to be able to add new SPFx webparts and redeploy the solution, but adding new extensions to a previously deployed solution seems to get ignored.

Comment: Also when I add manually another field I am receiving the error below: componentId: 202acb79-a40b-4456-8fcb-95faf0376db8, error: ***Manifest not found for componentId "202acb79-a40b-4456-8fcb-95faf0376db8".